# How entailment is different from implication?

Tags: logic, inference

I am studying logic in my AI course where I have come across the definitions of entailment and logic. However, I am having trouble differentiating between these two concepts. The definition of entailment in the book says "in all possible worlds where the premise is true, the conclusion is also true". Whereas, the implication says, "A implies B means, if A is true, then B is true". Looks like the difference is in "all possible worlds". Can anyone give me a real example that shows the difference between these two concepts?

Comment: Have you looked at this post? https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/72360/how-is-implication-same-as-entailment